# string class assignment operator overloading in c++

Tags: c++, string, overloading, destructor, operator-keyword

I defined my own string class, MyString. Everything works well until I assign one object to the other by the overloaded operator=. I know where the problem is but I don't know how to fix it. Any helps?

```
class MyString{
public:
    MyString( const MyString *strIni );
    MyString( const char *str);
    ~MyString();
    MyString& operator=( const MyString &str );
private:
    char *str;
}


MyString::MyString( const MyString *strIni ){
    this->str = new char[strlen(strIni->str)+1];
    strcpy(this->str,strIni->str) ;
};


MyString::MyString( const char *str){
    this->str = new char[ strlen(str) + 1 ];
    strcpy(this->str , str);
};

MyString::~MyString(){
    delete [] this->str ;
    cout << "successfully deleted..." << endl;
};


MyString& MyString::operator=( const MyString &str ){
    // temp obj holding the rhs
    MyString strTmp(str);
    // temp char pointer holding the rhs
    char *cTmp = strTmp.str;
    // temp obj holding this, later release this memory 
    strTmp.str = this->str ;
    // this holding rhs; assignment done.
    this->str = cTmp;
    return *this ;
};


int main(){
    {                                  // line 1
        MyString mystr1("string #1");  // line 2
        MyString mystr2("string #2");  // line 3
        mystr1 = mystr2;               // line 4
    }                                  // line 5
    return 0;
}
```

The problem of the code is: at line4, after the assignment the pointer in two objects mystr1 and mystr2 both point the same string "string #2". When the program jump out of the brackets at line 5, the destructors are automatically called by sequence: mystr2 and then mystr1. After mystr2 is destructed, the memory of "string #2" has been released. When the destructor of mystr1 is trying to release non-existing memory, the program crashed.

Anybody can help me to fix the overloading member function. When I assign mystr1 = mystr2, i can create a new string instead of making the two pointers pointing the same string.

Thanks a lot!!

---

---

Updates for further questions......
thank tons!!

actually, i am using copy-and-swap in the overloading function. based on @Mateusz Kołodziejski 's advice, i modified it:

```
MyString& MyString::operator=( const MyString &rhs ){
    if( this != &rhs ){
        // copy using constructor
        MyString strTmp(rhs) ;
        // swap        
        char *cTmp = strTmp.str;
        // strTmp will be destructed, thus the memory in this will be released
        strTmp.str = this->str ;
        // size of rhs
        const int str_size = strlen(rhs.str);
        this->str = new char[str_size+1];
        copy(rhs.str,rhs.str+str_size,this->str);
    }
    return *this ;
};
```

when the destructors are called, no crash. But if a printout member function is added, there seems another problem:

```
void MyString::printout(){
    int str_size = strlen(this->str);
    cout << "string size: " << str_size << endl ;
    for( int i=0;i<str_size;i++ ){
        cout << *(this->str + i);
    }
}
```

in main function:

```
int main(){
    {                                  
        MyString mystr1("string #1");  
        MyString mystr2("string #2");  
        mystr1.printout();
        mystr2.printout();
        mystr1 = mystr2;  
        cout << "after assignment: " << endl;
        mystr1.printout();
        mystr2.printout();             
    }                                  
return 0;
}
```

the results are:

```
string #1
string #2
after assignment...
string #2═²²²²
string #2
```

seems that mystr1 is not normal...

anybody can explain this for me?

Thank tons!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Comment: I sure hope this is for a school assignment or similar, as `std::string` already is good enough.

Comment: Use `MyString& MyString::operator=( const MyString &rhs ){` instead. Too many `str`s denoting different things. Perhaps then the problem will be clearer.

Comment: Don't redesign the wheel? This kind of bug is why you should use existing, well documented and tested classes. In this case `std::string`. You might want to investigate `strdup` to duplicate the string in your assignment operator though.

Comment: @nyarlathotep Yes I just realized, and that's the problem and I added an answer for it.

Comment: Stick to std::string and create convenience free functions. That way you have greater chance to be compatible with 3rd party software etc. You also can trust that there are no bugs in the string class you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obviously have to fix your operator=() implementation.

```
#include <algorithm>

MyString& MyString::operator=( const MyString &rhs ) // (1)
{
    if (this != &rhs) // (2)
    {
        delete[] this->str; // (3)
        this->str = NULL;

        const int str_length = strlen(rhs.str);

        this->str = new char[str_length + 1];
        this->str[str_length] = '\0';
        std::copy(rhs.str, rhs.str + str_length, this->str); // (4)
    }

    return *this;
}
```

1) Use "rhs" (right-hand-side) instead of "str" for your variable name to avoid ambiguity.

2) Always check if your object is not being assigned to itself.

3) Release the old allocated memory before allocating new.

4) Copy over the contents of rhs to this->str, instead of just redirecting pointers.

EDIT:

Added this->str = NULL; to avoid double deletion on possible exception from new, and later object deconstruction.

This is a naïve implementation - you have to be aware that new can throw an exception. Copy-swap idiom would be better here as suggested by @nyarlathotep and described here: [Copy-and-swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom).

Comment: Just a note: your code does not provide the "strong" exception safety: if new char throws an exception, `this->str` still points to unallocated space (the memory deleted before). That's why the swap idiom would be preferrable here.

Comment: on second thought it doesn't even provide the basic exception safety, since whenever MyString is destroyed, `str` would get deleted a second time...

Comment: @nyarlathotep True, it's just a naïve‎ implementation. Copy-swap idiom would be indeed better.

Comment: thanks for your comments. this is an interview question, not an assignment. i am using copy-and-swap in operator overloading function actually.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that with the declaration

```
MyString strTmp(str);
```

in the assignment operator, you call the default implicitly generated copy-constructor. And that constructor will simply just copy the pointer, not create a new pointer and copy the contents of the string.

The constructor you have taking a `MyString` pointer is *not* a copy-constructor, a copy-constructor would take a constant *reference* instead. If you change your constructor taking a pointer to `MyString` to take a reference instead, then it will work better.

Comment: even if OP did create a deep-copying copy constructor, the assignment operator would still use the `char*` from the temp object, which afterwards get deleted, right?

Comment: @nyarlathotep No, the OP swaps the pointers, so it's the old `this->str` that gets deleted.

Comment: ah yeah, missed that - could be `std::swap` for better readability ;)